# Ubuntu drivers for the Konica Minolta C200

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, printer

I need to find drivers for Ubuntu for the Konica Minolta C200, but the home page of Konica doesn't have any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Click on the dash.
2. Search for "printing".
3. Select **Add**.
4. Click on "Network printer".
5. Click on the drop-down.
6. Give it a few seconds for Ubuntu to find the printers on the network.
7. Select the Konica Minolta printer.
8. Select **Forward**, Ubuntu will then search for drivers.
9. Select the correct printer from database.
10. In the **Makes** field, scroll down to Konica Minolta. I selected the first driver after selecting **Next**. Printed a test page successfully.